# ReactJS: adding scripts to project Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, integration

I am trying to integrate a javascript project into my reactjs one. The plain `js` project augments images in 3D space using `matrix3d` `css`. https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/Matrix-Construction-Set I want this project to act separately in a modal inside my reactjs app.
There are lots of `js` files and I found that it's a headache to add simple `script` tags to a `reactjs` project, so I've started with a blank `js` file. Adding the empty file to the project raises the following `error` in the browser, files with content also raise the same `error`.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`